# Zoom on hover not working with right position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to create application which will zoom image on hover with jQuery. The problem is that image is not getting zoomed on right position and I am unable to figure out the problem.

```js
 zoomIn = function (event) {
  var pre = document.getElementById("preview");
  pre.style.visibility = "visible";
  if ($('#zoom1').is(':hover')) {
        var img = document.getElementById("zoom1");
  pre.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg')";
    }

  var posX = event.offsetX;
  var posY = event.offsetY;
  pre.style.backgroundPosition=(-posX*2.5)+"px "+(-posY*5.5)+"px";

}

zoomOut = function () {
  var pre = document.getElementById("preview");
  pre.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
#preview{
 margin-top: 10px;
 border:1px solid black;
 width:350px;
 height:500px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
#samples{
 text-align: center;
}
#samples img { 
 margin: 10px;
 display: block;
  border: 2px solid #6A6462;
}
#samples img:hover {
  cursor: zoom-in;
  border: 0;
  -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 7px 2px rgba(130,130,130,1),-1px -1px 7px 2px rgba(130,130,130,1);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 2px rgba(130,130,130,.7),-1px -1px 7px 2px rgba(130,130,130,1);
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 2px rgba(130,130,130,.7),-2px -2px 7px 2px rgba(130,130,130,1);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
 #samples img {
  display: inline-block;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6" id="samples">
   <img class="img-fluid" id="zoom1" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)" onmouseout="zoomOut()" src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
   
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div id="preview" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

For complete demonstration, I have uploaded the code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwsf8arL/3/).

Comment: where did you get 2.5 and 5.5 from?

Comment: It is multiplying position to zoom the image

Comment: No, I get that. But the specific values 2.5 and 5.5. Why 2.5 instead of 2.3? They feel arbitrary. Maybe a mathematical calculation between the image's size on the page and it's natural resolution would resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried it by replacing 2.5, 5.5 with 2, 5 but nothing change, you can also try to edit and run the code

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of mixed code and that can sometimes cause syntax errors or coding issues. I would consider moving it all to jQuery.

For Example, see the following:

```js
$(function() {
  function zoomIn(event) {
    var img = $(event.target);
    var pre = $("#" + img.data("preview"));
    var high;
    if ($(".highlight").length === 1) {
      high = $(".highlight");
    } else {
      high = $("<div>", {
        class: "highlight",
        width: Math.round(pre.width() / 5.5) + "px",
        height: Math.round(pre.height() / 2.5) + "px",
      }).css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }).appendTo(img.parent());
    }
    pre.css("visibility", "visible");
    if (img.is(':hover')) {
      pre.css("background-image", "url('" + img.attr("src") + "')");
    }

    var posX = event.offsetX;
    var posY = event.offsetY;
    high.css({
      left: posX + "px",
      top: posY + "px"
    });
    pre.css("background-position", (-posX * 2.5) + "px " + (-posY * 5.5) + "px");
  }

  function zoomOut(event) {
    $(".preview").css({
      "background-image": "",
      visibility: "hidden"
    });
    $(".highlight").remove();
  }

  $("img").mouseover(zoomIn).mousemove(zoomIn).mouseout(zoomOut);
});
```

```css
.preview {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.highlight {
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
  position: absolute;
}

.samples {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.samples img {
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #6A6462;
}

.samples img:hover {
  cursor: zoom-in;
  border: 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 2px rgba(130, 130, 130, 1), -1px -1px 7px 2px rgba(130, 130, 130, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 2px rgba(130, 130, 130, .7), -1px -1px 7px 2px rgba(130, 130, 130, 1);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 2px rgba(130, 130, 130, .7), -2px -2px 7px 2px rgba(130, 130, 130, 1);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .samples img {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 samples" id="sample-1">
      <img class="img-fluid" id="zoom-1" src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" data-preview="preview-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div id="preview-1" class="preview"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried to consider more portable script code. I suspect you will be having more than 1 sample image and possibly more than one preview area. You will see I adjusted the ID and classes of a lot of HTML Elements to make them easier to address.

To help tie the img to a specific preview window, I made use of the data attribute (`data-preview='preview-1'`). Again this helps make the code portable and useful for many images and previews or many images and 1 preview. The naming, `image-1`, `preview-1` etc is helpful for jQuery. You're not making big use of it, but something to consider.

The preview works and you cna now adjust your view values as you like. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it seems not solved the problem and also image is start flickering.

Comment: @PankajSharma it was working pretty well before adding the `highlight`. How did it 'not solve the problem'?